# Service gets killed when app removed from background tray in some devices

Tags: android

Hii I am starting a service from activity using intent method.If works fine in most of the devices but in some lenovo devices the service gets killed when I remove my app from device background tray.It happens only in lenovo devices.I have tried startforeground() but it doesn't helped me out.can anyone solve this issue.

Comment: This is caused by some device settings which cannot be done programmatically. For example, Huawei devices have their own energy management BESIDES the doze mode. There is nothing you can do against this, you can only study the devices and suggest the users to do their settings.

Comment: Example: In Huawei Ascend Mate 7, You have to enable "Auto Start" in the app settings, otherwise a broadcast will not be send. Also you have to whitelist the app, if not, no matter if your service is foreground, it will be killed.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs ok thanks a lot